# meteor angular collection find method not working

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to optimize my angular/meteor code.  I have a collection

`Customers = new Mongo.Collection("Customers");`

and the way I was displaying them was:

`ng-repeat="customer in customerController.customers | filter: {customerStore: myStore} ">`

and in my CustomerController

`this.customers = $meteor.collection(customers);`

This approach (while it works) is now starting to take up a lot of memory on the client's server as they are adding more and more stores.

So I tried to filter server side before sending information to the client.

NEW CODE:

collection code is the same

`Customers = new Mongo.Collection("Customers");`

ng-repeat code is different

`ng-repeat="customer in customerController.getCustomers(myStore) ">`

and my controller now has this method:

```
    this.getCustomers = function(findByStore){
        return Customers.find({customerStore.$ : findByStore});
    }
```

The problem with this is that it returns a new collection each time, so angular sees it as a different object and tries to re-render the page.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:21,%22oldVal%22:19%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:23,%22oldVal%22:21%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:25,%22oldVal%22:23%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:27,%22oldVal%22:25%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:29,%22oldVal%22:27%7D%5D%5D

`One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new array every time it is called.`

Someone suggested i try

```
return $meteor.collection(Customers.find({'customerStore.$' : findByStore}));
```

but then I get the error

```
TypeError: The first argument of $meteorCollection must be a function or a have a find function property.
```